# Let both the admin and post author update comment meta

Tags: posts, comments

I have a function which lets the post author set the "best comment".
I want the admins to also be able to set the "best comment".

Who can this be best achieved?

```
// Set Best comment for post
function select_best_comment($best_comment_id, $best_comment_parent_question) {
    // Prevent Non Logged In Users from making updates
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { return new WP_Error('not_logged_in_post', 'sorry cant do this'); }

    $post_data = get_post($best_comment_parent_question);
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Make sure the post author is selecting the best comment
        if ($current_user->ID == $post_data->post_author) {

            include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/translations.php');   

            global $wpdb;
            $get_comments = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "comments WHERE comment_post_ID ='". $best_comment_parent_post . "'" ;
            $best_post_comments = $wpdb->get_results($get_comments);

            $best_comment = get_comment($best_comment_id);

            foreach($best_post_comments as $comment) :
                setup_postdata($comment);
                update_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'best_comment', 'no');
            endforeach;

            $currentPointNumber = intval(get_user_meta($best_comment->user_id, 'points', true));

            $newPointNumber = $currentPointNumber + 2;  

            $best_comment_user = get_userdata($best_comment->user_id);

            update_comment_meta($best_comment_id, 'best_comment', 'yes');

            // Add 2 Points for being Selected as Best comment
            $has_been_best_comment = get_comment_meta($best_comment_id, 'has_been_best_comment_before', true);
            if ($has_been_best_comment == 'no' || $has_been_best_comment == '') {
                update_user_meta($best_comment->user_id, 'points', $newPointNumber);
                update_comment_meta($best_comment_id, 'has_been_best_comment_before', 'yes');
            }

            setcookie("best_comment_selected_".$best_comment_parent_post,"yes", time()+10);
            $post_data = get_post($best_comment_parent_post);
            wp_redirect($post_data->guid);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solved it with Mr. Birgire's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace

```
if ($current_user->ID == $post_data->post_author) {
```

with

```
if ( $current_user->ID == $post_data->post_author 
    || $current_user->has_cap( 'manage_options' ) ) {
```

to additionally allow users, with the correct [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), to vote for the best comment.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked for you, cheers